# Define Hotkey for "Build Project" in TeXlipse

Tags: texlipse

Is there a possibility to define a hotkey for "Build Project" in TeXlipse?
In my installation, Strg+B is shortcut for "Build all", which I never need. Can I use it for "Build Project" instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Option to alter or add hotkeys for TeXlipse can be found in the following menu:
Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys